# Dynamic block for optional elements

Tags: terraform

I have dynamic block on a variable.

```
  dynamic "settings" {
    for_each = var.settings
    content {
      id      = lookup(settings.value, "id", null)
      ...
    }
  }
```

But from the calling module, it not necessary that `settings` to always exists and sometime it would just be passed `null`.

```
settings = null
```

However, when this happens I get following while planning.

```
var.settings is null
Cannot use a null value in for_each.
```

So basically, I only want to dynamic block generation when the `settings` is not `null`. How best can I address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, you would not normally want to assign a `list` or `map` type variable to `null` to designate an undefined value. You would want to use the empty constructors `[]` for `list` and `{}` for `map` instead. This will give you the behavior you desire and promote clean code.

If you really want to assign `null` to a non `string` or `number` type, then you can use the [coalesce function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/coalesce.html) with a null coalescing pattern (some languages provide operators for this; e.g. `?:` in JS):

```
for_each = coalesce(var.settings, [])
```

and that will give you the behavior you desire. Note that it basically adds another layer to use the empty constructor as a backup/default, which is the best practices pattern advised at the beginning of the answer.